# Why does SqlClient use unnecessary XML conversion while passing SqlXml?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, sqlclient

I`ve got a question about passing xml datatype to a query from C# code.

First, here`s a table on SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dat] [xml] NOT NULL
)
```

Second, I have an application which is written on C#. And I insert rows into the `XmlTable` from the application.

Here`s the code:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("root",
     new XElement("abc", "123"),
     new XElement("cba", "321")));

var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(doc.ToString()));
var xml = new SqlXml(reader);

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
     using (var command = new SqlCommand("insert into XmlTable (dat) values(@data)", connection))
     {
          command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data", SqlDbType.Xml){Value = xml});
          connection.Open();
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Everything works fine, rows are inserted. But if I run the SQL Profiler and inspect the insert command, I see following:

```
declare @p3 xml
set @p3=convert(xml,N'<root><abc>123</abc><cba>321</cba></root>')
exec sp_executesql N'insert into XmlTable (dat) values(@data)',N'@data xml',@data=@p3
```

We can see that in spite of passing `SqlXml` type into a query `SqlClient` performs unnecessary conversion from string to XML. XML parser does waste work.

The question is: why does `SqlClient` do this way? And how can I make it do without extra conversion?

Comment: this code is used in high-load scenario and additional convertation makes it slower

Comment: Dmitriy: it's **conversion** (not *convertation*)

Comment: Also: which **version** of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sorry for my English:)
I use 2008 R2

Comment: No worries - you're English is much better than my Russian :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no converssion occuring in reallity. What you see is an artifact of Profiler/Trace having to somehow represent the [TDS RPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357576%28v=prot.20%29.aspx) call as a T-SQL batch you can copy paste and execute in SSMS. The *real* text executed is just `insert into XmlTable (dat) values(@data)` and `@data` type/value comes from the `ParamData` portion of the request. As with *any* wire protocol, serialization and encoding has to occur in the client and decoding and deserialization has to occur at the server. As a side note, there is no call to `sp_execute_sql` either, that is again an artifact of how Profiler/Trace displays an RPC call.

> *this code is used in high-load scenario and additional convertation makes it slower*

That is speculation. You should base performance analysis on [measurements and observations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182403.aspx).