# Insert date into table variable does not work in SSMS but works at runtime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

An application I am working on is exhibiting some strange behaviour that I cannot explain when it saves data. The application uses a custom c# data layer. When a save is made, it inserts data into a table variable then executes a stored procedure to save the data, passing the table variable as a parameter. The save works when the application runs, but when I profile the sql that is running, I cannot execute the queries in SSMS because of a conversion failure to datetime. An example of the SQL recorded by profiler is below, I've added in the table variable as well for reference.

table variable...

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ExampleType] AS TABLE(
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL DEFAULT (''),
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

sql from profiler...

```
declare @p1 dbo.ExampleType
insert into @p1 values(N'','2014-01-29 09:48:18.8000000','2014-01-29 10:05:31.9647267')

exec [dbo].[save_Example] @tableParameter=@p1
```

When the application is running, I can see the saved data in the table and the datetimes are truncated to the datetime format i.e. the last 4 characters are removed and the data is saved. Am I missing something in the profiler which allows the sql to run, or is there another explanation?

Comment: What happens when you try and run it in SSMS? An invalid date error? What is the default language setting for the two logins?

Comment: The error received when running the insert is 
    Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: The stuff shown in Profiler is just a textual representation of the actual calls. It does not actually execute that literal string [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619533/why-does-sqlclient-use-unnecessary-xml-conversion-while-passing-sqlxml/13621862#13621862).

Comment: Try to execute this regional-independent representation:
insert into @p1 values(N'','2014-01-29T09:48:18.8000000','2014-01-29T10:05:31.9647267')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given be Martin looks correct to me and explains the behaviour I'm seeing.

Link from his comment...

[Why does SqlClient use unnecessary XML conversion while passing SqlXml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619533/why-does-sqlclient-use-unnecessary-xml-conversion-while-passing-sqlxml/13621862#13621862)

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert it in a variable. E.g.

```
@CurrentDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-09 09:48:18')
INSERT INTO @p1 VALUES (.., @CurrentDate, ...)
```

Comment: Yes this would work, but it's not my question. The sql in my question is the output from SQL Server Profiler for all intents and purposes. Running this sql fails in SSMS but works when the application is running. Is there a setting that comes from the application which would allow the statement to run?